# C/C++ array of pointers to 2d arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get an array of pointers to 2d arrays of booleans. How can this be achieved?
This is for an Arduino (think they are a mix of C and C++?)

Comment: Do you want the declaration syntax, or what?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768294/how-to-allocate-a-2d-array-of-pointers-in-c

Comment: Are you looking for an array or dynamic allocation (i.e. an "array" [more or less] of a certain size known only at run-time)? This would be done differently in `C` than in `C++` for dynamic allocation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768294/how-to-allocate-a-2d-array-of-pointers-in-c

Answer (score 7):

Based on your description, I think you're looking for something like:

```
bool (*arr[K])[M][N];
```

It breaks down as

```
       arr                -- arr
       arr[K]             -- is a K-element array
      *arr[K]             -- of pointers
     (*arr[K])[M]         -- to M-element arrays
     (*arr[K])[M][N]      -- of N-element arrays
bool (*arr[K])[M][N]      -- of bool
```

Comment: is it possible to declare it without having to declare M and N, i.e if you wanted to have 2d arrays of different sizes?

Comment: No.  The size of the array is part of the type; e.g., a 3x4 element array of `bool` is a different type from a 4x5 element array of `bool`, and a pointer to one isn't compatible with a pointer to the other.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C++, and you don't want to input the size from the declaration, you can do that by allocating it dynamically.

```
int first_dim, second_dim;
// determine dimensions somewhere inside code

// create array of pointers to booleans
bool** arr[10];
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    arr[i] = new bool*[first_dim];
    for(j = 0; j < first_dim; j++){
        arr[i][j] = new bool[second_dim];
    }
}
```

Make sure you `delete` all of your arrays when you are done using them.

**NOTE**

When you are trying to allocate 2d arrays, don't think of them as matrices or tables, each storing a boolean. For example, take an array of `int`s, an array declared as `int arr[i][j]`, each element in the first "dimension" is of type `int*` and each element in the second "dimension" is of type `int`. So it is in fact an "array of arrays", if you will.

Comment: (note to OP, this will be less efficient though, because the 2-d arrays will not be contiguous)

Comment: maybe, but how else would he do it, since he does not want `first_dim` and `second_dim` to be known from the start? (see comments on answer by @JohnBode above)

Comment: he could allocate each `arr[n]` as an 1-d arrays instead of a 2-d array and manually index `arr[n][second_dim * i + j]` (that's what I would do, if performance mattered)

Comment: your last edit is somewhat misleading, btw, since it doesn't extend past 2d (with `bool arr[i][j][k]`, `bool[i]` is `bool (*)[k]`, not `bool**`...see [this](http://ideone.com/7SP9nu)

Comment: sure, I changed the type so he knows it's a separate example from the question he/she asked, but the point was to illustrate a better way to think about arrays. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I just mean that someone reading might assume that the first element of a 3-d array of `T` is convertible to `T**`, which is not the case; but anyway, they can read the comments so it's not a big deal.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying.

Comment: you can just link to the first answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920729/in-c-c-is-char-arrayname-a-pointer-to-a-pointer-to-a-pointer-or-a-pointe?rq=1), that's a good explanation.

Comment: (and technically with `bool arr[i][j]`, `arr[0]` is `bool [j]`. but it decays to `bool *`, if you want to be pedantic)

Answer (score 0):

An array of pointers to 2D arrays of booleans looks like this (both in C and C++ - pick one, they're not the same language, nor a mixture):

```
 typedef bool TwoDBoolArr[10][10];
 typedef TwoDBoolArr *TwoDBoolArrPtr;
 typedef TwoDBoolArrPtr TwoDBoolArrPtrArray[10];
```

You need the last `typedef`, of course.

If you want less typedefs and decreased readability:

```
typedef bool (*TwoDBoolArrPtrArray[10])[10][10];
```